# Post form using AJAX in Django

Tags: ajax, django

I'm trying to POST form in Django using Ajax. I've already done this way before but now i cant find whats wrong with my code. When submitting the form, ajax POST's to wrong URL even though i've provided the right URL. I want to post to "/upload/videoUpload/" but it keeps on posting to "/upload".Below is the code.

```
HTML:
<form id="videouploadForm" method="POST" >
  {% csrf_token %}

  <input  type="text" id="vidlc" name="video" value="submit" style="display: none" >
  <input type="submit" id="sBm120" style="display: none"/>
</form>

AJAX:
<script>
$('#sBm120').trigger('click');

$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#videouploadForm").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
             method:"POST",
             url:"/upload/videoUpload/",
             data: {
                    'video': $('#vidlc').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                    },
             success: function(data){
                if (data.status){
                    alert(data.status);
                    var result = " <video poster='{% static 'images/single-video.png' %}' style='height:30vh' controls='controls' width='100%' height='30%'><source src='http://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/"+data.filehash+"' type='video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'></video>";
                    document.getElementById("upv").innerHTML=result;
                }
             }
        });
        return false; //<---- move it here
       });

});
</script>

URLS.py:
path('upload/videoUpload/', uploadVid, name="uploadVideo"),
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use Django url template tags?
url:"/upload/videoUpload/",    to
url:" '{% url " uploadVideo" %} ",

Hope it works!

Sorry if you dont see properly, writing from my phone :)